# How to change a bg of ScrollView in my code and print the text on it?

Tags: python, kivy

My program parses the site at the click of a button and displays the text of the book on the user's screen. But since I'm a beginner, I can't find the ScrollView argument that would repaint it in the color I want. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I would be glad if someone could tell me how to display the text on the screen ScrollView, which is not black!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import requests

class MyButton(Button):
    color = (0, 0, 0, 1)
    valign = 'bottom'
    padding_y = 10
    background_color = (.93, .91, .67, 1)
    background_normal = ''


class Box(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    padding = [5,5,5,5]
    spacing = 10

    def on_kv_post(self, widget):

        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='И. С. Тургенев. «Отцы и дети»', on_press=self.btn_press))

    def btn_press(self, instance):
        self.clear_widgets()
        sc = ScrollView()
        x = 1
        data = ''
        while True:
            if x == 1:
                url = "http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=12021&p=1"
            elif x < 4:
                url = "http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=12021&p=" + f'{x}'
            else:
                break
            request = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
            teme = soup.find_all("p", class_="MsoNormal")
            for temes in teme:
                data += temes.text
            x = x + 1
        sc.add_widget(Label(text=f'{data}',color = (1,1,1,1)))
        self.add_widget(sc)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Box()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your `Label` to adjust according to its text. The easiest way to do that is by using the kivy language. Here is one way to do it:

Add a new class `MyLabel`:

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    pass
```

Use the new class in your python:

```
sc.add_widget(MyLabel(text=f'{data}',color = (1,1,1,1)))
```

Add use the kivy language to define the new class:

```
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string('''
<MyLabel>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
        ''')
        return Box()
```

Comment: Thank u. I did it, but i since have problem with the color of my scrollview. Dont know how to change it :(

My parsed text really output on the screen, but like on the black one) It is my problem now)